# Airflow Task Instance in Success state but no Start and End date (Not executed)

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow DAG which is scheduled to run once in a month. The DAG ran wonderfully till 01-08-2021. The next schedule was on 01-09-2021. The DAG and the Task were in SUCCESS state, but the DAG actually did not run. I couldn't see the start and end dates for the task instance. There are no logs too. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Airflow version : 1.10.6

Task Instances : All are in SUCCESS state
[image]

DAG details :

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| schedule_interval | 0 6 1 * * |
| max_active_runs | 0 / 16 |
| concurrency | 16 |
| default_args | {'provide_context': True, 'depends_on_past': False, 'start_date': <Pendulum [2021-05-01T00:00:00+00:00]>, 'retries': 1, 'catchup_by_default': False, 'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(0, 300)} |
| tasks count | 1 |
| task ids | ['GENERATE_INVOICE'] |
| filepath | invoicing.py |
| owner | airflow |

Comment: Maybe someone just marked it as Success? (check the logs) in any case you can clear the relevant tasks so it will run

Comment: There is only one task running in this DAG. I somehow tried to get the log from Airflow server.
[2021-09-02 05:25:06,827] {taskinstance.py:624} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: invoicing.GENERATE_INVOICE 2021-08-01T06:00:00+00:00 [success]>, dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'success' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
[2021-09-02 05:25:06,829] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-09-02 05:25:06,829] {local_task_job.py:91} INFO - Task is not able to be run